# Angular 2 Rxjs Timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I've been trying to get timeout working with my http Get calls but the Http calls are never timed out until no response is sent from server . What am i doing wrong ?

```
return Observable.interval(30000).startWith(0).flatMap(()=>{
            return this.http.get(someUrl).timeout(3000)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
        });
```

I'm using rxjs-5.0.0-beta.12 in my application

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you haven't heard... rxjs [5.5.6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/releases) is out now. :)

Comment: @R.Richards , thank you for the reply . i updated it to the latest version and it is still the same :(

Comment: Have you tried with `HttpClient` module?

Comment: What happens in your `this.handleError` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try [delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) operator to shift the emissions from an Observable forward in time by a particular amount.

```
 return Observable.interval(30000).startWith(0).flatMap(()=>{
                return this.http.get(someUrl).delay(3000)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
         });
```